# Where could I find Schema.msi and uisample.msi in Windows SDK

Tags: windows-installer

I'm going through the Windows Installer documentation and trying to complete one of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/importing-a-blank-database)

I need to create blank database(.msi) from samples Schema.msi and/or uisample.msi Where could I find them in Windows SDK in my system?

Microsoft provided link to *Windows SDK Components for Windows Installer Developers* But I don't see  mentioned any particular directory in the doc where it would located. I also tried to search it among SDKs installed on my PC but didn't find anything.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy I didn’t see any either but I used the orca tool provided in the sdk to create a blank database

Comment: yes, i did the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found similar by names files in google.
uisample.msi - https://github.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_sdk71/blob/master/Bin/msitools/Templates/MSI/UISample.Msi

schema.msi - https://www.exefiles.com/en/msi/schema-msi/